# TypeError: isSameTree() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q' in implementing a leetcode solution locally

Tags: python, class, binary-tree

I tried to test a leetcode solution on my local PC (WSL, python3) to have a better understanding of the problem

from https://leetcode.com/problems/same-tree/discuss/2594714/python-recurse-in-same-function
I modified it as

```
from typing import Optional
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

class Solution:
    def isSameTree(self, p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        
        if not p and not q:
            return True

        elif (p and not q) or (q and not p):
            return False

        return (
            self.isSameTree(p.left, q.left) and
            (p.val == q.val) and
            self.isSameTree(p.right, q.right)
        )

print(Solution.isSameTree([1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
```

I got (`binary_tree.py` is the name of the file for the above code)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_tree.py", line 24, in <module>
    print(Solution.isSameTree([1,2,3],[1,2,3]))
TypeError: isSameTree() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'
```

Seems I have a very basic issue in using python class. But, what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR

You need to instantiate the `Solution` class instance before calling the class function. i.e.,

```py
solution = Solution()
tree1 = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))
tree2 = TreeNode(1, TreeNode(2), TreeNode(3))
print(solution.isSameTree(tree1, tree2))
```

Or, you should add `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` decorator on the `isSameTree` function.

## Explanation

The error stack told you that `TypeError: isSameTree() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'`. In other words. `isSameTree()` needs three required arguments while you only pass two of them(`self`, `p`). The first list of your arguments is considered as a `self`.

By instantiating a `Solution` class instance, calling with it will pass `self` as an argument automatically. Or you can add `@classmethod` to pass `cls` automatically without instantiating a class instance. `@staticmethod` has similar effect but works differently. Check answers under this question for more information:
[Difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136097/difference-between-staticmethod-and-classmethod)

Also, passing lists into `isSameTree` doesn't work either. You should build `TreeNode`s by `TreeNode` class.

Comment: I used `solution = Solution()
print(solution.isSameTree(([1,2,3],[1,2,3])))` and still got ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "binary_tree.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(solution.isSameTree(([1,2,3],[1,2,3])))
TypeError: isSameTree() missing 1 required positional argument: 'q'```  :(

Comment: Thanks. It led to `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'left'` :(, I tried to input as in leetcode ...

Comment: @Chungji plz check the updated answer above. Leetcode's checker hides lots of details from you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Leetcode binary tree looks confusing indeed.